# Time zone from ISO 8601

Tags: r, string, datetime, iso8601

When having time string in ISO 8601 format like this one:

```
"2016-07-04T17:00:00+02:00"
```

how can I get timezone as numeric vector from it in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As variant, this way may be used:

```
getTimeZone = function(time)
{
  last = substring(time, nchar(time), nchar(time));
  if(last == 'Z')
  {
    return(0);
  }
  else
  {
    mins = as.numeric(substring(time, nchar(time)-1, nchar(time)));
    hours = as.numeric(substring(time, nchar(time)-4, nchar(time)-3));

    timezone = hours + mins/60;
  }
}
```

And now, when executing this:

```
a = getTimeZone("2016-07-04T12:00:00Z")
b = getTimeZone("2016-07-04T12:00:00+02:30")
a
b
```

We get next:

```
[1] 0
[1] 2.5
```